# Query identification by input

Tags: sql, oracle

```
column_name="something with 10"
column_name ="something with 10 and more"
```

Lets consider I have database records in the column like above. My logic is that if I put column_name= "something%" ,(column name contains %) this will be taken as a wild card search and will be a like query. And if I don't specify a % in the column_name column_name="something with 10", this will be consider as a equal search

1. Request column_name="something%"
   query - select * from table where column_name like 'something%'
   And this gives me both the records
2. Request column_name="something with 10"
   query - select * from table where column_name='something with 10'
   this gives me only the record "something with 10"

Now suppose I also want to store "%" in the column name like this

```
column_name="something with 10%"
column_name="something with 10% and above"
```

As per my current logic if I request

1. column_name="something with 10%"

this will be taken as a like query
query - select * from table where column_name like 'something with 10%'

And this gives both records , but I actually meant to get my record of "something with 10%"

So my question is , how would I identity if the user wants to use a equal query or like query ?since % is also would be in the column name , this is a contradictory because In my logic I consider % as wild card and will be considering this as a like query instead of a equal query. Or is there a way we can handle this effectively in Oracle SQL?

My input would be column_name='' , in this format always

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand value is only interpreted as a wildcard when it is part of a `like` predicate, so

```
where somecolumn = 'something with 10%'
```

will be treated as an equality test, not a wildcard, so it will only match `'something with 10%'`, and not `'something with 10% off'`.

If you want to escape a wildcard (i.e. match the `_` or `%` characters literally), then define an escape character:

```
where somecolumn like '% with 10\%' escape '\'
```

Comment: Yes i agree. But the problem is there is no way i can identify whether the api request meant equality or a like search. For example  

i would get a request like this /myapi/search?column_name='Something with 10%'
My current logic is that I treat it as a like when there is a % in the query parameter value. Or else it will be equality check.  That is the problem. So as an api owner I am not sure if the user meant a like search by putting wildcard or the user actually meant to get the record with "something with 10%" as an equality check. @William Roertson

Comment: Then it seems you have an API design issue. Do you want users to be able to use `_` and `%` characters as SQL wildcards or not? I'd guess the expectation is usually that they should be treated as normal characters, in which case you could escape them.

Comment: Yes I want the users to able to use % as a wildcard.

Comment: In that case use 'like'. I don't see there is anything you can do from the database side to detect how the user wants to interpret wildcard characters, unless you provide a checkbox or something in the UI.